# RAM for late 2008 Macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I'm looking to upgrade the RAM in my late 2008 Macbook, see the spec below.

A few people have mentioned getting [Crucial](http://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/) RAM but I'm unsure of what specific RAM to get and what the limit is. Or if there's better/cheaper options than Crucial.

I'm looking to get the max amount possible I can fit in.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: have you entered the model in Crucial's memory finder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.0-aluminum-13-late-2008-unibody-specs.html) :

RAM-Type = PC3-8500-DDR3 SDRAM @ 1066 Mhz

Supports officially max. 4GB and unofficially max. 6GB, 
but indeed a total of 8GB on ROM Version MB51.007D.B03 
and if running Mac OS X 10.6 or higher.

Apple released an update (including 8GB support) [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL974).
Also check for information about it [here](http://blog.macsales.com/9102-secret-firmware-lets-late-08-macbooks-use-8gb).

And if you are unsure, which to buy: here are some on [amazon.co.uk](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0031GNYBW/)

Comment: Ok thanks. So if I bought 4GBx2, it could use a minimum of 4GB and a maximum 8GB of it? My ROM version is different so guessing it wouldn't use the maximum of it... but there's a chance it *could*?

Comment: @Rob I added a firmware update link in the answer so you can use the full 8GB.